# tags: renaming "matrix-product" to "matrix-multiplication"

Tags: discussion, tags

I feel that we should rename [matrix-product](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-product) to [matrix-multiplication](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-multiplication) since it seems it is the more common terminology.

Any opinions?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a reasonable proposal.